# Is the same kernel version 4.4.0-1016-aws different on Ubuntu 16 and 14?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, drivers, kernel, amazon-ec2

I built a kernel module fc.ko on Ubuntu 16.04 for kernel 4.4.0-1016-aws.  The I copied the kernel module to a Ubuntu 14.04 running the same kernel version 4.4.0-1016-aws but got error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /opt/fc/agent/modules/4.4.0-1016-aws/fc.ko: Invalid module format
```

Does that mean the same kernel version 4.4.0-1016-aws is different for Ubuntu 16 and 14?

Update: I tried building my code on Ubuntu 14 against the 4.4.0-1016-aws kernel headers but the code failed to compile because kernel definition of the sock_recvmsg() function prototype is different from Ubuntu 16's 4.4.0-1016-aws kernel.  Here is the difference:

Ubuntu 16:/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1016/include/linux/net.h:

```
int sock_recvmsg(struct socket *sock, struct msghdr *msg, size_t size,
                 int flags);
```

Ubuntu 14:/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1016/include/linux/net.h:

```
int sock_recvmsg(struct socket *sock, struct msghdr *msg, int flags);
```

It looks like the same kernel version on Ubuntu 16 and 14 are indeed different.

Comment: A different `libc6` and a different `gcc` version will cause "Invalid module format".

Comment: Thanks.  It seems not just the gcc or libc could be different, some kernel function prototypes are also different.